# Need Help Understanding Why My Usage of the find() Method Isn't Executing Correctly

Tags: python, string, function, methods, find

Write a function called string_finder. string_finder should
take two parameters: a target string and a search string.
The function will look for the search string within the
target string.

The function should return a string representing where in
the target string the search string was found:

If search string is at the very beginning of target
string, then return "Beginning". For example:

```
string_finder("Boston Common", "Boston") -> "Beginning"
```

If search string is at the very end of target string,
then return "End". For example:

```
string_finder("Boston Common", "Common") -> "End"
```

If search string is in target string but not at the
very beginning or very end, then return "Middle. For
example:

```
string_finder("Boston Common", "ton") -> "Middle"
```

If search string is not in target string at all, then
return "Not found". For example:

```
string_finder("Boston Common", "Idaho") -> "Not found"
```

Assume that we're only interested in the first instance
of the search string if it appears multiple times in the
target string, and that search string is definitely
shorter than target string.

I am able to write a function that utilizes conditionals (if, elif, and else) and the find() method in Python 3. In some of my conditionals with the find() method, I'm using all three parameters for the find() method, which are string, starting index and ending index.

```
def string_finder(target_string, search_string):
    if search_string.find(target_string, 0, len(search_string)):
        return "Beginning"
    elif search_string.find(target_string, -1, -(len(target_string) - len(search_string))):
        return "End"
    elif search_string.find(target_string):
        return "Middle"
    else:
        return "Not found"
```

Below are some lines of code that will test your function.
You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your
function with different inputs.

If your function works correctly, this will originally
print: Start, Middle, End, Not found, each on their own
line.

```
print(string_finder("Boston Common", "Boston"))
print(string_finder("Boston Common", "ton"))
print(string_finder("Boston Common", "Common"))
print(string_finder("Boston Common", "Idaho"))
```

which should print

```
Beginning
Middle
End
Not found
```

However, with my current code I get:

```
Beginning
Beginning
Beginning
Beginning
```

I can't figure out how I messed up my conditionals and how to tweak. Also, I'm open to any better ways of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second if should be "elif". It works if u do it like this:

```
def string_finder(target_string, search_string):
    if search_string.find(target_string, 0, len(search_string)):
        print("Beginning")
    elif search_string.find(target_string, -1, -(len(target_string) - len(search_string))):
        print("End")
    elif search_string.find(target_string):
        print("Middle")
    else:
        print("Not found")
string_finder("Boston Common", "ton")
```

Comment: you are correct about the second if being an elif. I had that originally and was testing line by line to get a sense of how the program was running, and I forgot to change back.

Even then with that correction, I still get all values returned as Beginning. What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, let me do a little research, and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so it's returning 'beginning' simply based upon the fact that you can do the find operation .ALA: if "True" return "Beginning" It might take me a bit more time trying to figure out how to do what you're trying to do, but if you were to make the first part of the if statement. 'if 0==1", than it will return End, because it goes to the next elif statement before issuing a response.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` function ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)) returns -1 when it does not find the substring (and returns the lowest indice where it found the string), and -1 is interpreted as `True` by python ([docs for truth/false in python here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), therefore the first `if` will always evaluate to true.

You should check if the value returned is different from `-1`. Or if you want, you can check if the value return to tell where python found the string:

```
def string_finder(target_string, search_string):
    start_index = search_string.find(target_string)
    end_index = start_index + len(target_string)
    if start_index == -1: # Not found, find returns -1
      return "Not found"
    elif start_index == 0:
      return "Beginning"
    elif end_index == len(search_string):
      return "End"
    else:
      return "Middle"
```

Let me explain the code idea:

As the docs for `find` says, it "Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found". So, `start_index` represents where in the `search_string`  the `target_string` starts. The `end_index` then represents where in the `search_string` the  `target_string` ends. So, if you have `start_index` as 0 (first position), it is in the beginning of the string. If you have `end_index` equals the `len(target_string)` it goes until the end of the `search_string`.

Comment: I think I follow what you said, however if you run your code as it, it fails to run because index has no defined value (and from what I can tell, nothing in the function is assigning index a value). Is there something I am overlooking with your code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write `start_index` instead of `index`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm more lost. I see in your edited code, index is still being used for end_index = index + len(target_string) even though nothing is defined for index. Is end_index == len(target_string)?

Comment: Corrected it again. Let me explain the code idea. As the docs for `find` says, it "Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found". So, `start_index` represents where in the `search_string`  the `target_string` starts. The `end_index` then represents where in the `search_string` the  `target_string` ends. So, if you have `start_index` as 0 (first position), it is in the beginning of the string. If you have `end_index` equals the `len(target_string)` it goes until the end of the `search_string`.